# Check if the selected item in a listbox contains specific characters

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to figure out how to check if a listbox contains a specific string at a selected  index, but i can't figure it out. It's an WAF project.

```
private void UpdateGUI(string name, double price)
{
    //Check if the seat is already reserved??
    //Check if the seat is already canceled??

    int index = lstSeats.SelectedIndex;
    if (index < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item in the list!");
        return;
    }

    string strOut = string.Empty;
    string strReserved = "Vacant";

    if (rbtnReserve.Checked)
    {
        strReserved = "Reserved";
    }

    else
    {
        name = string.Empty;
        price = 0.0;
    }

    strOut = string.Format("{0,3} {1,14} {2,11} {3,13:f2}", index + 1, strReserved, name, price);
    lstSeats.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    lstSeats.Items.Insert(index, strOut);
    lblNumOfReservedSeats.Text = numOfReservedSeats.ToString();
    lblNumberOfVacantSeats.Text = (totalNumOfSeats - numOfReservedSeats).ToString();
    lblTotalNumOfSeats.Text = totalNumOfSeats.ToString();
}
```

Basically, i don't want to reserve a seat (in the cinema) that already has been reserved, or if the seat already is cancelled, i don't want to cancel it again. Any suggestions?

Or would it be better to check in the following code?:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = string.Empty;
    double price;

    bool inputOK = ReadAndValidateInput(out name, out price);

    if (inputOK)
    {
        if (rbtnReserve.Checked)
        {
            numOfReservedSeats++;
        }

        else 
        {
            numOfReservedSeats--;
        }
        UpdateGUI(name, price);
    }
}
```

Comment: winforms, wpf or something else?

Comment: Also extremely unclear what you want actually. Which specific characters? Where do you want to check it? Which line? My guess is you should do something like `listbox.Text.Contains(...)` or something similar.

Comment: I´d suggest to define a seat-class for your purpose and within this class create a member for reserved-state and cancelled-state as well.

Comment: Sorry guys for my very unclear description, completely new at C#. Anyway, Tafari has answered the question. Thanks guys for taking the time, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

for WFA and checking if an item contains given string use this:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            int itemAtPostion = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            string reserved = "Reserved";

            if (listBox1.Items[itemAtPostion].ToString().Contains(reserved))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("We are sorry, but this seat is reserved!");
                //your code
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am such a noob in programming, especially in C#. It's actually WFA (Windows Forms Application) I was probably unclear before. It isn't actually a character as in a char i am looking for, but a specific string, let's say "Reserved" on the row that has been selected. So if that row contains "Reserved" i want to alert the user that that specific row cannot be reserved again.. I hope i am making some sense.

Comment: I have updated my answer for you, now it works for WFA and checks if given item contains particular string. If it is what you want please rate up and accept as an correct answer : ) If not feel free to give me more explanations on what do you want and I will try to do my best.

Comment: Also added 'an alert' for a user if it's reserved.

Comment: Thank you Tafari for the answer, it works perfectly! Also sorry for being so unclear, i guess you'll learn this stuff eventually :) I can't Vote Up your answer since i haven't got 15 reputations yet =/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one. It's so simple

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each i In ListBox1.Items
        If i.ToString.Contains("your specific characters") Then
           //what happen if it true
        Else
            //what happen if it false
        End If
    Next
    //what happen when its finish work
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use C#:

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (var i in ListBox1.Items)
  {
    if (i.ToString().Contains("your specific characters"))
    {
        //what happen if it true
    }
    else
    {
        //what happen if it false
    }
  }
  //what happen when its finish work
}
```